# nginx/gunicorn + Django: subdomain configuration for third party application integration

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, subdomain, mattermost

I am building a regular django project - the difference is this:

1. I want the django website to **only "work"** on a specified subdomain - for example, `http://www.foo.mydomain.com`
2. I want to use an entirely different application to run on another specified subdomain - e.g. `http://www.foobar.mydomain.com`

How do I setup a django project, so that it only runs on a specific subdomain, and does not intercept requests to other subdomains - so other other applications can run on other subdomains on the same parent domain?

**[[Note 1]]**

The second application (running on the other subdomain is **not** a django app). In fact, it's [mattermost](https://about.mattermost.com/), that I want to run on the other subdomain - so I can integrate mattermost into my website.

**[[Note 2]]**

I'm using nginx + gunicorn as the server

Comment: How about using [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) ??. So for the 1st website it'll be `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.foo.mydomain.com']` and for the 2nd `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.foobar.mydomain.com']`.

Comment: How about configure your server to redirect traffic depending on the subdomain?

Comment: @nik_m That could probably work, but I wouldn't know hoe to do that (I'm using gunix +nginx). Would you know how to redirect based on subdomain? An example config file would be great

Comment: There are several sources/examples out there. How about [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578628/redirecting-a-subdomain-with-a-regular-expression-in-nginx) one ? I'm not an nginx expert. I'm just starting to learn it, though!

Comment: @nik_m That could potentially be useful, I'll experiment and see if that works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate `server` block for each domain. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

```
server {
    server_name www.foo.mydomain.com;
    ...
}
server {
    server_name www.foobar.mydomain.com;
    ...
}
```

Where a `server_name` match cannot be found, `nginx` will use the default server. So define a catch-all server block to prevent `nginx` using one of the server blocks above.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    deny all;
}
```