# Nginx SubDomain Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I have multiples subdomains that I want to redirect in nginx or php like that

```
Example: test.test2.domain.com to domain.com/test/test2
```

It's possible to do a 301 Redirect in nginx so in php I can get the parts test and test2 as params ?

Thanks

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/14502147/4875631 and add another variable in there. If it doesn't work, post back with what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
server {
  server_name test.test2.domain.com;
  location / {
    return 301 domain.com/test/test2;
  }
}
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-permanently-redirect-subdomain-to-specific-url

Comment: thanks, but I need something dynamic, I have multiples domains!

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your nginx configuration file

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name test.test2.domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com/test/test2/$request_uri;
}
```