# Nginx www to non-www redirect

Tags: nginx, cloud66

I need to add www to non-www redirect to nginx config. Here's the part of the config file (seems like whole config is too long for stack overflow):

```
user                            nginx;
worker_processes                1;
error_log                       /var/deploy/mydomain/web_head/shared/log/nginx_error.log;

events 
{
  worker_connections          1024;

}

http 
{
  gzip                        on;

  ...

  server {
        server_name www.mydomain.com;
        return 301 $scheme://mydomain.com$request_uri;
    }

    server 
    {
    listen                  80 default_server;
    server_name             _;

    rails_env               production;
    passenger_enabled       on;

    root                    /var/deploy/mydomain/web_head/current/public;

    client_max_body_size    50m;
    # redirect to 503 if maintenance page present
    if (-f $document_root/cloud66_maintenance.html) 
    {
      return 503;
    }

    # redirect on errors
    error_page              500 502 504  /50x.html;
    error_page              503 @maintenance;

    # handle error redirect
    location = /50x.html
    {
      root html;
    }

    location @maintenance
    {
      error_page 405 = /cloud66_maintenance.html;
      if (-f $document_root/cloud66_maintenance.html)
      {
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /cloud66_maintenance.html break;
      }
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
    }



    try_files $uri /cloud66_maintenance.html @passenger;
    location @passenger
    {
      passenger_enabled           on;
      passenger_min_instances     5;
      passenger_set_cgi_param     HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO $scheme;
    }

    location ~ \.php$
    {
      deny  all;
    }
  }


}
```

It didn't work. I even tried adding following block to the end:

```
server {
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://mydomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

And also tried replacing `server_name _;` with `server_name mydomain.com.`.

Thanks!

Comment: did you reload nginx settings? because you did it correctly

Comment: yes, it has been reloaded. hm, weird.

Comment: are u visiting the exact `www.mydomain.com`? also ps: you don't need the `server_name _;` if you want to match all, you can remove it entirely

Comment: yes, visiting exact www.mydomain.com. CNAME is set properly. As I mentioned I also tried server_name mydomain.com instead of server_name _. Got nginx error page with a hint to check error log but error log was empty...

Comment: add this line to your server blocks `error_log /var/log/[error log name]` then reload and do it again, you might also add `access_log`

Answer (score 1):

Cloud 66 automatically reloads the configuration if you are using CustomConfig. You can try this one:

```
if ($http_host = www.mydomain.com) {
   rewrite  (.*)  http://mycomain.com$1 permanent;
}
```

This can be under your `server` section

Comment: seems like the best practice is to have two server codes in this case. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www .. that's why I'm trying the above code, Khash.

Comment: That seems a bit excessive but if it works. I posted the code from our own nginx configuration (although ours is the other way: non-www to www).

Answer (score 1):

Add a new server block at the end of your configuration file.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.your-domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://your-domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

[A detailed tutorial on enabling www redirect with nginx can be found here](http://www.crimsonhack.com/articles/how-to-enable-www-redirect-ngnix/)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using dnsimple url forwarding service: https://dnsimple.com/url-forwarding-301-redirect. Works great without the need to edit nginx config.