# NGINX Rewrite - HTTPS/www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, nginx, https

I'm trying to get my site so that every variation of domain.com will redirect to https://www.domain.com. I'm using a combination of tools to do so .. One is the NGINX config file which begins with:

```
server {
            listen  80;
            server_name domain.com;
            return       301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
    }
server {
            listen          80;
            server_name     localhost www.domain.com;
            root            /usr/local/nginx/html;
```

I've also got a rule set up in my CDN to proxy all content through HTTPS:

```
if ( $scheme = http ) { 
  REWRITE RULE ^ https://$http_host$request_uri permanent 
}
```

Almost every variation works, except https://domain.com .. it should redirect to https://www.domain.com, but it doesn't load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may help:

```
server {  # redirect _all_ http requests to https server
    listen 80;
    return  301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost .domain.com ;
    root    /usr/local/nginx/html;

    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return  301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP connection using another port rather than the standard 80, should listen the port 443. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure#Difference_from_HTTP):

> HTTPS URLs begin with "https://" and use port 443 by default, whereas
>   HTTP URLs begin with "http://" and use port 80 by default.

See also this: [nginx HTTPS serving with same config as HTTP](https://serverfault.com/questions/10854/nginx-https-serving-with-same-config-as-http). From this page:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    # other directives
}
```

Also this other page has a http / https solution: [Nginx no-www to www and www to no-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www)