# From www to the root domain (301)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What's the canonical way to do a 301 redirect from **any url** which has `www` at the beginning to the root domain name - `www.domain.com` (or `www.domain.com/something`)  to `domain.com`? And assuming there's also `sub1.domain.com` and, of course, there shouldn't be a redirect.

Is it `before_filter` in `ApplicationController` or something else?

Comment: you should define this in nginx, more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-ww

Comment: @mymlyn, if I'm using something else, not nginx?

Comment: youre not using any http server in production? imo this exact redirection should be handled by your http server and not your application

Comment: @mymlyn, I'm. So redirection by web server is better than by application?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the `request` and do necessary redirections. You are right, it is done in `application_controller.rb`, something along these lines:

```
  before_filter :needs_redirection

  def needs_redirection
    redirect_to 'domain.com' if request.original_url.include? 'www.domain.com'
  end
```

Comment: Andreika, `'www.domain.com/something'` doesn't literally mean `something`, it means `anything`, any url at all.

Comment: isn't doing the same thing via nginx better (or whatever web server I'm using)?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp won't lie - I haven't used it yet, so can't tell