# How to redirect my wordpress site's Domain in Nginx no-www to www

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I want to redirect my domain example.com to www.example.com

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com configuration is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;               
                }

error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
```

}

What changes should I do in this code?

I have added this line :
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;

for wordpress permanent link correction.

Comment: This question has been answered hundreds of times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nginx no-www to www and www to no-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www)

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate server block to listen for the non www and 301 it to www like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name netmark.com;

    return 301 $scheme://www.netmark.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this tutorial](http://highend-computers.com/how-to-redirect-wordpress-to-another-domain) to move a domain to another domain but from what I understand you only want to change the actual domain prefix.