# Nginx Permanent Redirect (NON-WWW to WWW) not working

Tags: php, redirect, drupal, nginx, permanent

Hi Guys I want my all NON-WWW url request to move permanently and also rewrite to WWW and I have tried to follow existing solutions at these as well
[Nginx no-www to www and www to no-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www)
but still it did not work for me.

e.g. I want example.com or example.com/* to rewrite to www.example.com or www.example.com/*

I am running PHP-FPM with nginx and memcache

below is my config

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name abc.com;
return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;

        root /srv/www/abc;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
.......
}
```

Below is my curl response

```
neel:~ nilesh$ curl -I http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 21 Aug 2015 19:00:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
X-Drupal-Cache: HIT
Etag: "1440178291-0"
Content-Language: en
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Link: <http://example.com/>; rel="canonical",<http://example.com/>; rel="shortlink"
Cache-Control: public, max-age=1800
Last-Modified: Fri, 21 Aug 2015 17:31:31 +0000
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Vary: Cookie
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: Did you try giving `-L` or `--location` to curl? Cause curl won't follow redirection if you don't.

Comment: I tried but -L just prints out html. Well -I returns headers and if the config would have worked it would have return permanently moved.

Comment: Then is this your local env or live? Only thing that comes to me, if it's live dns can cause something like this.

Comment: This is on live environment and deployed on ec2 and have good traffic. There is A record entry for the ec2 IP on godaddy dns

Answer (score 1):

I have finally SOLVED my issue. I checked my nginx.conf and it was pointing to  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled and /etc/nginx/conf.d

**my nginx.conf->**

```
 ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

I finally copied my file from sites-available to folder sites-enabled. infact I kept it synced.

below is the code i used under my server tag

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        root /srv/www/example;
#rest config goes below
```

.......

Now all my non-www traffic is 301 permanently moved and rewrite to www with the above code.

I made a curl call to non-www and I got the following correct response.

```
neel:~ nilesh$ curl -I http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 27 Aug 2015 08:39:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 193
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.example.com/
```