# Nginx 301 + 2 domains?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure nginx to respond to two domains: `domain1.com` & `domain2.com` yet if someone tries to access `domain2.com` he will 301 redirected to `domain1.com` (with the full request params), how can I do that? i am getting redirect loops all the time.

Comment: can you share your config?
it should look like this
```server {
server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com; 
rewrite ^ $scheme://www.domain2.com;
}```

Comment: Thanks Ereli, already solved this issue!

Comment: Your question is the same as [how to redirect www to no-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www) (as www and no-www are 2 different domains). You haven't shown your existing config, which makes it somewhat impossible for anyone to say why you're getting a redirect loop.

Comment: @AD7six i've published my config as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! managed to resolve it with two `server` entries:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;
        return 301 $scheme://domain1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;

    # Root directory
    root /home/myuser/sites/domain1.com/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    // rest of configs

    }
```