# how to redirect no-www to www under jwilder/nginx-proxy?

Tags: nginx, docker

I use nginx docker(https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy), but find it no way to amend .htaccess as mentioned here([Nginx no-www to www and www to no-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www)). Could anyone tell me how to redirect no-www to www under the above jwilder/nginx-proxy.

Answer (score 5):

This may be a little late but I found the solutions here to be too much faffing, so I created the `adamkdean/redirect` lightweight companion service for `jwilder/nginx-proxy`.

The example below simply shows HTTP but you can hook this up to HTTPS if you like using the [letsencrypt-nginx-proxy](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion) companion service by JrCs.

For `adamkdean/redirect`, you simply provide two environment vars, one of the redirect location and one of the status code (which can be either 301, 302, 303, or 307) with the default being 307 (if you omit REDIRECT_STATUS_CODE).

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  redirect:
    image: adamkdean/redirect
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=example.com
      - REDIRECT_LOCATION="http://www.example.com"
      - REDIRECT_STATUS_CODE=301

  example:
    image: example
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=www.example.com
```

Find the repo here: https://github.com/adamkdean/redirect

Comment: @VonC Ha ha. No offence intended, just sometimes you need a solution out of the box that is repeatable and reliable with minimal to zero customisation.

Comment: That seems a nice solution and works in reverse i.e. www to non-www but can it handle multiple sites? For example, can I redirect two hosted sites - www.domain1.com to domain1.com and www.domain2 to domain2? If so, it could be a neat way of handling the redirection of different sites in one place rather than through DNS for each one.

Comment: @mharran as it stands, no, but it is something that I'm planning to add as I find myself using many instances for single redirects.

Comment: That's great, @AdamKDean, it will be really useful.

Comment: For anyone reading, this has now been done and multiple redirects is now supported.

Comment: @AdamKDean how can i also hook it to HTTPS? If I add port "443:443" it conflicts with nginx-proxy

Answer (score 3):

You would need to:

- `git clone https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy`,
- amend [`nginx.tmpl`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/nginx.tmpl) and
- rebuild the nginx-proxy image yourself.

That way, you would generate a new nginx-proxy image which does include the directives you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the redirect without changing the nginx.tmpl. There is the option to import further configuration files either directly under `server {` or in the default location `location / {`. See https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#per-virtual_host.

Create and mount a file `/etc/nginx/vhost.d/your-website.com` or `/etc/nginx/vhost.d/your-website.com_location` with the following content:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.your-website.com/$1 permanent;
```

Answer (score 2):

## Introduction

Unfortunately you did not specify your technical setup. 
So i do have to make some assumptions.
Let's assume that you want to start a blog using a fully supported docker environment with following docker images:

- nginx-proxy,
- docker-gen,
- letsencrypt,
- ghost (blog software) and
- mariaDB.

Therefore you registered a domain with the name *personalblog.com*.
You already set up an DNS A record to the IP address where your blog content will be hosted. So you have an A record for *personalblog.com* to that IP address and an A record for *www.personalblog.com* to that IP address.

## Requirements

Please follow the instructions to setup your nginx-proxy with letsencrypt environment (you will find in these repositories a full instruction for setup):

- https://github.com/evertramos/docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

After finishing the nginx-proxy setup for docker, please follow these instructions for setup your blog software with ghost and maria db:

- https://github.com/LuisArteaga/docker-ghost-mariadb-letsencrypt

There might be a docker bug when pulling the latest image for ghost. So change in the docker-compose.yml *ghost:latest* to *ghost:1.22.1*

## Redirect non-www to www for jwilder/nginx-proxy

In the nginx-proxy setup (described by @evertramos repository above) you specified in the .env file your Nginx File Path (Check out the line with *NGINX_FILES_PATH=/path/to/your/nginx/data*). With this you created a directory outside of the nginx docker container.

#### Step 1

`cd /path/to/your/nginx/data/vhost.d/
sudo vim personalblog.com`

#### Step 2

In the new file personalblog.com you add following line:
`return 301 http://www.personalblog.com$request_uri;`
Save the file with ESC and `:wq`

#### Step 3

Go to your path where your docker-compose.yml for nginx lies and do:
`sudo docker-compose up -d --force-recreate`

## Notes

The file that you are creating under /path/to/your/nginx/data/vhost.d/ has to be the name of your domain. In this case you want to redirect from *personalblog.com* to *www.personalblog.com*, so the file name is **personalblog.com**. If you followed the instructions of the repositories above you will automatically redirected to https. So don't worry if you just redirect to `http://www.personalblog.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to update the variable VIRTUAL_HOST to have both the www and non-WW hostname:

VIRTUAL_HOST=www.target-host.com, target-host.com

Answer (score -2):

First you need to clone git using: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

Then amend it using `nginx.tmpl` and at last rebuild it using `nginx-proxy` image yourself.

Comment: That seems to be an exact copy of my answer, is it not?