# Nginx Redirect not working for more than one parameter

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to prefix queries with `www` using nginx.

**Problem**: While `domain.com` and `domain.com/about` gets prefixed with www, `domain.com/c/3kl239zz` doesn't (at least it's not displayed in the browser bar).

Here are the nginx blocks:

```
# redirect block
server {
  listen                  80;
  server_name             domain.com;
  return                  301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri?;
}

# website block
server {
  listen                  443 ssl;
  server_name             www.domain.com;

  ...
}
```

**Additional info**:

- We have 2 additional nginx blocks catering to subdomains i.e.
  `test.domain.com`.
- In `domain.com/c/3kl239zz`, `c` is an Angular
  state, while `3kl239zz` is a db document reference.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7958540/2097224... Look at your `$request_uri` try it without `?`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Just tried, didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

there is no problem with nginx . domain.com/about means domain.com with about state but where you are typing  domain.com/c/3kl239zz this means domain.com with c folder with 3kl239zz state , got it. if you want this data you can give it in params domain.com/c?id=3kl239zz

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense. Do you know if there's a way to make `/c/3kl239zz` work? If possible, I'd like to retain this style for url shortening purposes.

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to address why it's not prefixing `domain.com/c/3kl239zz` with `www`