# Redirect www to non-www with Meteor and Meteor UP

Tags: redirect, meteor, nginx, meteor-up

How do I redirect everything on `www.site.com` to `site.com`?

I use MUP to deploy my application to Digital Ocean. So far I am thinking of either adding a `CNAME` for www (couldn't get that to work), or add a meteor package that redirect server side (something like [wizonesolutions:canonical](https://atmospherejs.com/wizonesolutions/canonical)), or `SSH` into the server and [change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www) NGINX manually.

What is the recommended approach for doing this?

Comment: Go to your DNS settings and set up redirect from www.site.com to site.com. This is most easiest and convenient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to mention that I use `SSL (HTTPS)`. With that it's not possible to redirect with a `CNAME` in the domain settings.

I could not change the NGINX settings since every time I deployed, the container got replaced with a new one and MUP itself does not have any settings for this.

The recommended and very nice solution was to use [wizonesolutions:canonical](https://atmospherejs.com/wizonesolutions/canonical). Just remember to set `ROOT_URL` variable in the `mup.js` setup file to the desired URL (https://www.yourdomain.com or https://yourdomain.com)

Answer (score 0):

as of 2022, (mup v1.5.7), you can do as follow :

`mup.js`

```
  proxy: {
    domains: 'example.org,www.example.org',

    ssl: {
      letsEncryptEmail: 'hello@example.org',
      forceSSL: true,
    },

    nginxServerConfig: './nginx.conf',
  },
```

---

`nginx.conf`

```
# Start custom configuration: redirect www to non www
server_name example.org www.example.org;
if ($host = www.example.org) {
    return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}
# End of custom configuration
```

Nginx says "if is evil", but it's the only solution i've found to interoperate with the automatically generated nginx config.

you could even try to use a more generic approach :

```
server_name ~^.*$;
if ($host ~ ^www\.(?<domain>.+)$) {
  return  301 $scheme://$domain$request_uri;
}
```

Here, you won't have to maintain any website url.