# Django redirect non www to www is redirecting to mysite/mysite/wsgi

Tags: django, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm redirecting non www to www in my django project. So far its in fact working by setting the PREPEND_WWW = True in my settings.py

But somehow when I enter mysite.com it will redirect me to www.mysite.com/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

Is it possible just to redirect it to www.mysite.com?

Comment: Not sure what might be causing the problem. But, usually it's a better idea to do this kind of redirect outside Django (e.g. at Nginx). It  would solve your problem anyway http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all .pyc files from my project and ran the server with the python manage.py runserver --noreload command + reloaded my apache service.

Somehow this fixed my problem. Django was acting weird!