# nginx forward www to https

Tags: nginx, https, no-www

I'm using nginx if I call www..com my browser cant find anything and is not shown the page https://.com and .com is working perfectly.

Here is my conf file, have tried some different configurations but they dont help to solve my problem

```
# HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name <MY-DOMAIN>;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl                 on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/<MY-DOMAIN>/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<MY-DOMAIN>/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE-1

error.log

```
2017/03/12 16:40:17 [warn] 23185#23185: *59 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/1/00/0000000001 while reading upstream, client: 91.22.34.177, server: <MY-DOMAIN>, request: "GET /bundle.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js", host: "<MY-DOMAIN>", referrer: "https://<MY-DOMAIN>/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget *server_name* directive:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name <MY-DOMAIN>;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Anyway `/var/log/nginx/error.log` show you everything ))

Comment: Reread your question - It's not enough clear for me - If you want readr from www.blabla.com to `https://blabla.com` you need
`server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.blabla.com;
    return       301 http://blabla.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  blabla.com;
    ...
}`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www?rq=1

Comment: strange even two server block declaration it doesnt help and the error.log is also not very helpful... -.-