# How to redirect all not www to www with Nginx in a WordPress installation created with Easy Engine

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, nginx

I'm needing help in configuring redirect in wordpress / nginx.

I've toured a lot of tutorials that teach you how to do not www for www in nginx.

But unfortunately none has worked so far. I do not know what could be happening.

I did an install on my Ubuntu 16.04.2 64x server from Digital Ocean using
The Easy Engine that installs Nginx.

The installation came out perfect this all funcionano less the redirection of not www for www in my WordPress.

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this around here.

From now on, I welcome you for any orientation.

Below I leave the settings of my server name.

```
server {

    server_name meusite.com.br www.meusite.com.br;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/meusite.com.br.access.log rt_cache;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/meusite.com.br.error.log;

    root /var/www/meusite.com.br/htdocs;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    include common/php.conf;
    include common/wpcommon.conf;
    include common/locations.conf;
    include /var/www/meusite.com.br/conf/nginx/*.conf;

}
```

Remembering that I have already used the solutions of all these tutorials below:

https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/www-non-www-redirection/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

https:// www. vultr.com/docs/nginx-redirects-for-non-www-sub-domains-to-www

[Nginx no-www to www and www to no-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www)

https:// stackoverflow.com/questions/42228191/nginx-redirect-non-www-to-www-https

https:// serverfault.com/questions/624848/redirect-non-www-to-www-over-ssl-with-nginx

https:// serverfault.com/questions/610722/wordpress-non-www-to-www-redirect-loop-in-nginx

https:// www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

https:// www.nginx.com/blog/converting-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/

http:// community.rtcamp.com/t/redirect-www-to-non-www-and-non-www-to-www/7323

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what I use to redirect from non www to www in nginx.

```
 server {
      listen 80;
      server_name mysite.com;
      return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.com;
}
```

Then for the normal server:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /path/to/website/root;
    index index.html index.php;
    server_name wwww.mysite.com;

   <any extra configuration you need here>

}
```

Here is my entire configuration for my WordPress site in Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /websites/mysite.com/htdocs;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.mysite.com

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
         log_not_found off;
         access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
         allow all;
         log_not_found off;
         access_log off;
    }   

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello friend, I'll try this.

You could pass me the paths where you are putting these settings to see if my paths are similar to yours.

Thank you!

Comment: I placed most of the configuration and files in different locations then default. If you have a pretty default nginx installation your configuration file is probably located in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/ directory, do you have one site?

Comment: Yes, I have a wordpress website!
My files are also in /etc/nginx /sites-available/

Comment: So you can change the configuration for the website there for the parts you need.

Comment: Do you use SSL in your installation?

Comment: No, do you have a certificate for your website?

Comment: Yes I use certificate's let's encrypt my settings are different from yours.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/e29a457841dc4dd60006 here are more examples

Comment: I did my installation with easyengine. screencast: https://www.screencast.com/t/KC4GvoXtlm