# How to configure nginx www and non-www domains

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, dns, no-www

I'm following two tutorials ([1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [2](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/319/2237/how-can-i-set-up-an-a-address-record-for-my-domain)) to setup two domains on my server but after many attempts, I can't figure out how to have both domains working and www redirecting to non-www.
At the moment, with the same server block files and DNS Records, both work in different ways, I think it could be some cache but I don't know why it is.
The server block files are:

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name domain.com;

       root /var/www/domain.com/html;
       index index.html;

       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
}
```

And both have the same DNS Records:

```
A Record | @ | VPS IP
A Record | www | VPS IP
```

And the problem is that domains don't work properly.

- "domain1.com" don't work (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error on Chrome).
- "www.domain1.com" redirects to the default page (the block server that is set as default) and not to the correct one (the one that is in the block server file of domain1)
- "domain2.com" works fine.
- "www.domain2.com" don't work (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN).

I restarted nginx and the VPS but both still work in different ways (as I described).

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www

Comment: Thanks, @Timino, I have already read that post in the past and it didn't work because I had another DNS Records, but now it works with one of the answers of that thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a way to do it.

It's a server block config that I have already proven but with other DNS (in the past), so now it is working with the following combination:

**DNS Records (same as above):**

```
A Record | @ | VPS IP
A Record | www | VPS IP
```

**Server block config:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name www.domain.com;
        return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name domain.com;

        root /var/www/domain.com/html;
        index index.html;
}
```

Thanks to @Timilo for the suggestion that moved me to try it again.