# Unable to redirect www to non-www in nignx

Tags: nginx

Read and implemented everything but not able to redirect my domain www to non-www.

*If I browse without www my site is opening fine.*

**My Config is as follows:**

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

**My current server-block config is as follows:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    #return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
    #return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com;

        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.php index.html;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that. How can I debug what is going wrong?

Comment: First of all, check if your www and non-www domains resolve to the same IP addresses. Also, you have different listening sockets in your www and non-www - IPv6 (`listen [::]:80;`) is only used for non-www one - this will cause issues if you are using IPv6.

Comment: Can you please give me more details on it, what do you mean by, www and non-www domains resolve to the same IP addresses, how can I assure?

Comment: I am using Amazon Cloud Server

Comment: Ping www.example.com and example.com, do they resolve on the same IP ?

Comment: without www ping was hitting the server IP, but with www response is "Ping request could not find host www.example.com. Please check the name and try again."

Answer (score 1):

try to add this server block:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

restart Nginx:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Note that if you are using `HTTPS`, the listen directive should be set to port `443` instead of `80`

Use this `curl` command to ensure that the `non-www` domain redirects to the `www` domain (replace the highlighted part with your actual domain):

```
curl -I http://example.com
```

You should get a `301` Moved Permanently response, that shows the `www` redirect location, like this:

Sample Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 04 May 2015 18:20:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 193
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: I have tried everything, please give me the steps how can I diagnose what is going wrong in my server block? plz note: I want to redirect from www to non-www because my non-www site is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Modify first block

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.example.com;
return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

then
`sudo service nginx restart`