# Force www in nextjs project

Tags: .htaccess, web, next.js

***I want to always force www in my nextjs project. I tried this in htaccess file but doesn't work. Anyone can help me ?***

Answer (score 0):

it seems it's not so much related to the `next.js` and it depends on the tools you're using for deploy.

for apache:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

for Nginx:
[Nginx no-www to www and www to no-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www)