# Can't remove www from https links nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

**What I want to do**

I want to redirect all to https non-www

```
http://mytestwebsite.com      > https://mytestwebsite.com
http://www.mytestwebsite.com  > https://mytestwebsite.com
https://www.mytestwebsite.com > https://mytestwebsite.com
```

I tried this

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name www.mytestwebsite.com mytestwebsite.com;

    return 301 https://mytestwebsite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    if ($host = www.mytestwebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://mytestwebsite.com$request_uri;
    }

    server_name www.mytestwebsite.com mytestwebsite.com;
    ssl_certificate /home/mysite/ssl.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/mysite/ssl.key;
    # SSL configuration
    # Other configurations
}

server {
         server_name "~^www\.(.*)$" ;
         return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri ;
}
```

With this, all works fine, except

```
https://www.mytestwebsite.com > https://mytestwebsite.com
```

I always get `https://www.mytestwebsite.com`......

I tried many solutions from stackoverflow, google etc.. and nothing works.
https always have www...

**How to remove www from https links?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx no-www to www and www to no-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www)

Comment: Thanks, already tried but unfortunately doesn't work..

Comment: Your configuration looks fine. The last `server` block does nothing, but the `if` block should work unless there is a typo or you forgot to restart the server. Did you forget to reset the browser's cache when you tested it? It's safer to test redirection using `curl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly check if your **dns record** is configured for `mytestwebsite.com`. If it is not, the add **A record** via domain provider dashboard.

Then you can have something of this sort:

```
server {
  #listen and all other stuff

  server_name www.mytestwebsite.com;

  location / {
    return 301 https://mytestwebsite.com/$uri;
  }
}
```

What it will do is if any request is sent to `www.mytestwebsite.com`, it will be `301 Moved Permanently` to `mytestwebsite.com`.